# RawPrinterHelper Not reponding at all no errors in vb

Tags: vb.net, file, printing, type-conversion, network-printers

I have something like this in my raw printer:

```vb
Partial Class packstation_pick
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected exUtility As New ExceptionUtility

    Protected Sub btnFind_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
        Dim d As DataAccess
        lblMsg.Text = ""

        If txtPickSlip.Text.Trim = "" Then
            lblMsg.Text = "* Enter Pick Slip Number"
            txtPickSlip.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If txtPickSlip.Text.Contains("-") Then ' using code 39 and dash character didn't seem to have any side effects
            ' format pickslip-database
            Dim pickinfo() As String = txtPickSlip.Text.Split("-")
            If pickinfo(1) <> DataAccess.databasename(Session.Item("DBCONNECTION")) Then
                If Not switch_database(pickinfo(1)) Then
                    lblMsg.Text = "cannot switch to database " & pickinfo(1)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                txtSIIFileno.Text = ""
            End If
            txtPickSlip.Text = pickinfo(0)
        End If
        txtSIIFileno.Text = txtSIIFileno.Text.Trim
        If txtSIIFileno.Text = "" Then
            d = New DataAccess(Session.Item("DBCONNECTION"), False)
            txtSIIFileno.Text = d.get_current_sii_fileno(txtPickSlip.Text)
            d.close(False)
            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSIIFileno.Text) Then
                lblMsg.Text = "* Enter Sii File Number"
                txtSIIFileno.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        d = New DataAccess(Session.Item("DBCONNECTION"), False)
        Dim dbname As String = d.getclient()
        '  Dim diorecom_paycapture As String = ""
        ' diorecom_paycapture = d.getdefaultvalue("DIORECOMCAPTURE")

        Dim celine_api As String = d.getdefaultvalue("CELINEAPI")

        Try
            If d.pickslipvalidate(txtPickSlip.Text) Then
                Dim designer_code As String = ""
                Dim xsiifileno As String = ""
                d.get_siifilenos_table(txtPickSlip.Text, designer_code, xsiifileno)
                If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(designer_code) Then
                    designer_code = d.getdefaultvalue("SIICSCODE")
                End If
                Dim distribution_database As String = d.getdefaultvalue("DISTRIBUTION_DB")
                Dim distribution_connection As String = DataAccess.sii_connection("", distribution_database)
                d.close(False)

                Dim d_sii As DataAccess = New DataAccess(distribution_connection, False)
                Dim file_code As String = d_sii.check_sii_file(txtSIIFileno.Text)
                d_sii.close(False)

                If file_code = "" OrElse (designer_code <> "" AndAlso designer_code <> file_code) Then
                    lblMsg.Text = "* Enter valid Sii File No!"
                    txtSIIFileno.Focus()
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                Session.Add("pickslip", txtPickSlip.Text)

                d = New DataAccess(Session.Item("DBCONNECTION"), True)
                d.updatesiifile(txtSIIFileno.Text, txtPickSlip.Text, True)
                d.close(True)

                If trPicker.Visible = True Then

                    txtPicker.Focus()

                    If ValidatePicker() Then
                        d = New DataAccess(Session.Item("DBCONNECTION"), True)

                        d.update_pspicker(txtPickSlip.Text, txtPicker.Text.Trim.ToUpper)
                        d.close(True)

                    Else
                        d = Nothing
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                End If


                If celine_api = "Y" Then
                    d = New DataAccess(Session.Item("DBCONNECTION"), True)

                    Dim ds As New DataSet

                    d.order_info_by_pickslip(ds, txtPickSlip.Text)

                    If ds.Tables("ORDER").Rows.Count = 0 Then
                        lblMsg.Text = "* No Pickslip Available!"
                        d.close(False)
                        txtPickSlip.Text = ""
                        txtPickSlip.Focus()
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    If ds.Tables("ORDER").Rows(0).Item("OHUSER2").ToString.Contains("CCWD_20") Then
                        If ds.Tables("ORDER").Rows(0).Item("OHUSER3").ToString = "EHD/HD" Then

                            Dim strResponse As String = ""

                            strResponse = d.celecom_order_read(ds.Tables("ORDER").Rows(0).Item("PSOHXACT"))

                            If strResponse.Contains("PAYMENT_OK") OrElse strResponse.Contains("PREPARED") Then
                                'gp ahead
                            ElseIf strResponse.Contains("LOCKED_BY_CELINE") Then

                                d.close(False)
                                lblMsg.Text = strResponse & " - Please wait and try again later."
                                Exit Sub
                            ElseIf strResponse.Contains("CANCELED") Then

                                d.cancel_order(ds.Tables("ORDER").Rows(0).Item("PSOHXACT"), 1, False)

                                lblMsg.Text = strResponse
                                d.close(True)
                                Exit Sub
                            ElseIf strResponse.Contains("VALIDATED") Then
                                d.close(False)
                                lblMsg.Text = " * Payment Status Not Received. Current Status: VALIDATED. Please wait and try again later."
                                Exit Sub
                            Else
                                d.close(False)
                                Try
                                    lblMsg.Text = strResponse.Split(",")(1).Split(":")(1).Replace("""", "")
                                Catch ex As Exception
                                    lblMsg.Text = "* Invalid Order Status!"
                                End Try

                                Exit Sub

                            End If
                        End If

                    End If

                End If

                d = Nothing

                Dim cookie As New HttpCookie("DBSIIFILENO", dbname & "|" & txtSIIFileno.Text)
                cookie.Expires = Now.AddDays(1)
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)

                If cbAddressValidation.Checked Then
                    Response.Redirect("ups_address.aspx?next=packstation_carton.aspx&psxact=" & txtPickSlip.Text, False)
                Else
                    Response.Redirect("packstation_carton.aspx" & IIf(cbCreateCarton.Checked, "?CARTON=1", ""), False)
                End If
                Exit Sub
            Else
                If Not d Is Nothing Then d.close(False)
                lblMsg.Text = "* Open pick slip not found"
                txtPickSlip.Focus()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            exUtility.WriteToErrorLog("Packstation_pick.aspx", "btnFind_Click()", ex.Message & " StackTrace: " & ex.StackTrace & " DB: " & HttpContext.Current.Session("DBCLIENT") & " User: " & HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString.ToUpper)
            lblMsg.Text = ex.Message
            If d IsNot Nothing Then d.close(False)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Function ValidatePicker() As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPicker.Text) Then
            lblMsg.Text = "* Missing Picker ID!"
            Return False
        End If

        Dim d As New DataAccess(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DBCONNECTION"), False)

        Dim validlogin As String = ""

        validlogin = d.UserByUserID(txtPicker.Text.Trim.ToUpper)
        d.close(False)

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(validlogin) Then
            lblMsg.Text = "* Invalid Picker"
            Return False
        End If

        Return True
    End Function




    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Dim d As New DataAccess(Session.Item("DBCONNECTION"), False)
            If d.getdefaultvalue("SIIFILENO") <> "TABLE" Then
                txtSIIFileno.Text = d.get_current_sii_fileno("")
            End If

            Dim PSPicker As String = ""
            Dim AddressVal As String = d.getdefaultvalue("ADDRESSVALIDATION")
            PSPicker = d.getdefaultvalue("PSPICKER")
            If PSPicker = "Y" Then trPicker.Visible = True
            txtPicker.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off")
            If AddressVal = "Y" Then cbAddressValidation.Checked = True
            d.close(False)
            lblMsg.Text = ""

            Session.Remove("CARTON")
            Session.Remove("CTNNO")
            Session.Remove("pickslip")
            Session.Remove("STATUS")
            Form.DefaultButton = btnFind.UniqueID
            txtPickSlip.Focus() ' make sure it has the focus

            If Not IsNothing(Session("LASTCARTONSIZE")) Then
                cbCreateCarton.Visible = True
                'cbCreateCarton.Checked = True
            Else
                cbCreateCarton.Visible = False
                'cbCreateCarton.Checked = False
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Function switch_database(newdatabase As String) As Boolean
        Dim d As New DataAccess(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DBCONNECTION"), False)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        d.getuserdesigners(ds)
        d.close(False)
        For Each dr In ds.Tables("DATABASES").Select("DCONNECTION like " & DataAccess.sqlquotestring("%" & newdatabase))
            If dr("dconnection").ToString.EndsWith("=" & newdatabase) Then
                Session.Item("DBCONNECTION") = dr("dconnection")
                Session.Item("DBCLIENTNAME") = dr("dname")
                Session.Item("DBCLIENT") = newdatabase
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function
    Protected Sub cbCreateCarton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbCreateCarton.CheckedChanged
        txtPickSlip.Focus()

    End Sub
End Class
```

On page load, I would like to call print automatically
after server.transfer to new page

```vb
RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(strPrinter, path)
```

My `SendFileToPrinter` is calling perfectly which has no error but still it's not printing.

I did not get any response from the printer.